# second-order buttworth low pass filter in python code

Tags: lowpass-filter

[image]

[image]

i have difficulty in understand the function freq_response(),i have already knew that the coefficient is for 2-order butterworth LPF, i want to change it into 3-order,what does the "phi" and "r" mean？

Answer (score 1):

That is not great code. It's too convoluted to tell whether it's correct or not (at least for me).

> what does the "phi" and "r" mean？

1. $\phi$ is apparently the sine squared of half the normalized frequency
2. $r$ is supposed to be the magnitude squared of the filter

> i want to change it into 3-order,

That code doesn't scale. Throw it away and start from scratch using the definition of the Z-transform and complex numbers.